# Apply String directly in NLTK pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nltk

I am new to NLTK,
I am trying to get Company Names from a String. This is the code i wrote. But its not giving the output.Is it possible to give String value directly in patterns? Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk import pos_tag,RegexpParser
text="CompanyName1 GmbH is from Germany. CompanyName2 Inc is from America. ComapnyName3 corp is from India."
pattern = r"""
P: {<NNP>+<GmbH|Inc|corp>}
"""
for sent in sent_tokenize(text):
   sentence = sent.split()
   print("Parts of speech :",pos_tag(sentence))
   PChunker = RegexpParser(pattern)
   output= PChunker.parse(pos_tag(sentence))
   for subtree in output.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'P'):
     # print(subtree)
     print(' '.join([x[0] for x in subtree]))
```

Comment: Are company names always single words (chunks of non-whitespace chars)?

Comment: No. Eg: Confiance Enterprises GmbH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may combine the regex and NLTK features here.

```
import re
...
text="CompanyName1 GmbH is from Germany. CompanyName2 Inc is from America. Comapny Name3 corp is from India."
for sent in  sent_tokenize(text):
    tagged = pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))
    joined = ' '.join(["{}<{}>".format(word,tag) for word,tag in tagged])
    print([x.strip().replace("<NNP>", "") for x in re.findall(r'((?:\S+<NNP> )+)(?:GmbH|Inc|corp)<NN[^>]*>', joined)])
    print('-------- NEXT SENTENCE ----------')
```

This outputs:

```
['CompanyName1']
-------- NEXT SENTENCE ----------
['CompanyName2']
-------- NEXT SENTENCE ----------
['Comapny Name3']
-------- NEXT SENTENCE ----------
```

The `joined = ' '.join(["{}<{}>".format(word,tag) for word,tag in tagged])` part creates a temporary sentence with tags appended to the words. The regex is `((?:\S+<NNP> )+)(?:GmbH|Inc|corp)<NN[^>]*>`, it matches

- `((?:\S+<NNP> )+)` - Capturing group 1 (it will be the output of `re.findall`): 1 or more non-whitespace chars followed with `<NNP>` and a space, all repeated 1 or more times (due to `+`)
- `(?:GmbH|Inc|corp)` - a non-capturing group that matches any of the the 3 alternatives (`|` is an alternative operator)
- `<NN[^>]*>` - a `<NN` + any 0 or more chars other than `>` and then a `>`.

To get the final result, the tags should be removed from the company names, so you may just use `x.strip().replace("<NNP>", "")` - strip the whitespace from start/end of the found match and remove the `<NNP>` tag using a mere `str.replace` method.